# CSS Half/Half Background

Tags: html, css, background

I have searched every where for an answer to this. i have a design that I am trying to code using divs and css. There is a gradient in the top half of the image that goes form left to right and is different colors. The problem I am finding is that I can do it half and half, and I was able to finally get the image to center but part of it is hiding underneath the background.

(http://pretty-senshi.com/final-final.html) <-- sample of the design so far

http://pretty-senshi.com/original.png <-- the original design

http://pretty-senshi.com/gradient.png <-- the background gradient that needs to be repeated on the X-Axis only.

```
<html> <LINK href="style.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet> </head> 
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div id="container"><div id="rightHalf">

    </div><center><img src="images/Final-Final_02.png" id="picture"></center>
    <div id="header2">

    </div>

    </div>
    </div></div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {background: url(images/final-final_01.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;}
div#container {
width:100%;}
picture {z-index: 999;}

#rightHalf {
background: url(images/final-final_03.png);

background-repeat:repeat-x;
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Instead of z-index: 1 try z-index:-1 on your #rightHalf div.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy! YES! Thank you! It completely works now!

Comment: Some things that won't help your problem, but need to be addressed anyway: You should have a doctype declaration. There is no <head> tag, yet you're closing it anyway. If you're using an external stylesheet to begin with, don't add style attributes to your body tag. The center tag has been deprecated for a long time now, try margin: 0 auto; instead. Finally, I'd look into properly nesting and indenting your HTML tags so that they're easy to read. Doing these things will not only make your code function better across browsers, but will also make you look more professional. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess using the z-index = -1 for the #rightHalf will solve the problem.